# Fetching value using LISTAGG but avoid grouping of a table used in Inner join

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, aggregate-functions, string-aggregation

Hi I have an Oracle query like

```
select listagg(name,',') within group (order by name)
from table t1 
inner join table t2 on t1.id=t2.id
inner join table t3 on t1.value=t3.value
```

but later i needed to fetch 2 more columns from another table t4 so i joined t4 but when i join the listagg is giving repeated values separated with comma

```
select listagg(name,',') within group (order by name)
from table t1 
inner join table t2 on t1.id=t2.id
inner join table t3 on t1.value=t3.value
inner join table t4 on t1.id=t4.id
```

I want to fetch these new two columns without effecting the LISTAGG function.

Answer (score 3):

By adding the joins you are getting names repeated in the results.  Assuming your joins are correct, you could use DISTINCT to resolve this:

```
select listagg(name,',') within group (order by name)
from (select distinct name
      from table t1 
      inner join table t2 on t1.id=t2.id
      inner join table t3 on t1.value=t3.value
      inner join table t4 on t1.id=t4.id
)
```

Comment: This would create unique values within in the listagg field, but the rows on your final output would have duplicate rows?